# Python List Index out of Range when Appending a List

Tags: python, list

When appending to a list in Python, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/HARDRIVE/Java/Python/Test.py", line 16, in <module>
cities.append([1][i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The list `cities` is initialized here:

```
cities = [[0 for x in range(math.factorial(CITIES)+3)] for x in range(math.factorial(CITIES)+3)]
```

Why is it producing this error when there is obviously enough space for the append operation (I gave the list three more than it needed)? What should I do to fix it? This is the loop that contains the line of code:

```
for i in range(0,CITIES):
cities.append([1][i])
cities.append([1][i])
holder=cities[0][i]
cities[0][i]=cities[CITIES+1][i]
cities[CITIES+1][i]=holder
```

Thanks

Comment: `[1][i]` is trying to get the ith element of a list containing only `1`.

Comment: How does it contain 1? I initialized it to the factorial of `CITIES` (`CITIES` is 5)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the 2D array? Does that mess up `append`?

Comment: `cities[1]` refers to the 1st element of the list `cities`, `[1]` is a list only containing one vlaue,`1`.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do with this `cities.append([1][i])`?

Comment: Show the part of the code that contains the `cities.append([1][i])` to give us some context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you expect `cities.append([1][i])` to do?

Comment: @phimuemue To add another list to the end of `cities`, by simply expanding the 2D list. That last sections should equal `1,1`, throughout the rest of the array, at the X index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you might want to append a new list onto your existing lists

```
cities.append([1,i,0])
```

as an aside you can reproduce the issue easily as mentioned in the comments without anything to do with appending

```
for i in range(3):
   try: print i, [1][i]
   except IndexError: print "LIST:[1] has no index", i
```

Comment: So, how do I fix my problem then? This isn't technically an answer.

Comment: change your append to actually append a list ... as I show in the first block of code ... it is showing you what you did wrong ... I cant help you more than that without significantly more details ... your question technically should be closed (and there are pending votes on it for just that), since it is not at all clear what your desired behaviour is

Comment: I flagged it for a moderator to check it out